# How get DependencyProperty from PropertyPath?

Tags: silverlight

I have PropertyPath and object instance. I need change property using DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty ...)

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/a/11570213/ help?

Comment: give screen short or code for better understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, I would suspect that you can just use the PropertyPath.Path property as the name of the dependency property. In general PropertyPath can be very complex and you'd need to do your parsing on the Path property to see what it actually denotes. Take a look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertypath.path.aspx) and read the remarks section for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a UserControl or a TemplateControl, you could use the "new" keyword on the property you want to override.